# Lumen return information about deleted record, always gets ModelNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, lumen, lumen-5.3

I'm trying to use Pusher with Lumen to push events to clients to get data refresh.
I've created very simple Event:

```
class CarEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast{

    use SerializesModels;

    public $car;
    private $type;

    public function __construct( Car $car, $type )
    {
        $this->car = $car;
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['car'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
     {
        return $this->type;
     }
}
```

And I'm successfully fireing it in my controller using `Event::fire(new CarEvent($car,"add"));`
Inside Pusher console I get below event:
[image]

My problem begins when I try to send event when record is deleted, below is my code:

```
public function deleteCar($id){

    $car = $this->cars->findOrFail($id);
    $car->delete();

    $oldCar = new Car;
    $oldCar->id=$id;
    Event::fire(new CarEvent($oldCar,"delete"));
    return Response::deleted();
}
```

This always gives `ModelNotFoundException` because model with given Id not exists anymore, which is true.

My question is how I can fire event that will tell that car with specific id is deleted. I don't want to create another class that will extend Event and will be used only for delete, I'd like to use my existing CarEvent class.

I need to pass simple object with just Id property like so:
[image]

Can I create Car object and set it `Id` property and somehow disable getting rest if data from database when model is serialized?

Answer (score 1):

The problem doesn't come up when serializing but rather when unserializing.
You see, your Event uses the `SerializesModels` trait. This trait has the following method:

```
protected function getRestoredPropertyValue($value)
{
    if (! $value instanceof ModelIdentifier) {
        return $value;
    }

    return is_array($value->id)
            ? $this->restoreCollection($value)
            : (new $value->class)->newQuery()->useWritePdo()->findOrFail($value->id);
}
```

This trait serializes models as a `ModelIdentifier`, which just holds the class name and the id. When unserializing, the model is fetched fresh from the database using that information. In your delete case, the `findOrFail` makes it, well, fail.

I guess you can think of a solution that suits your needs now. This one, for instance, I guess should work for different models; if you know you just want this for Car models you can make a more straightforward one.

```
protected function getRestoredPropertyValue($value)
{
    if ($this->type == 'delete' && $value instanceof ModelIdentifier) {
        $model = (new $value->class);
        $pk = $model->getQueueableId();
        $model->$pk = $value->id;

        return $model;
    }


    return parent::getRestoredPropertyValue($value);
}
```

---

**Update**
Probably it's cleaner to have separate Events as you suggest. All constructors should receive a Car model, and for the delete case you create a simple object with the attributes you need.

```
abstract class CarEvent extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{

    use SerializesModels;

    public $car;
    protected $type;

    public function __construct(Car $car)
    {
        $this->car = $car;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['car'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

---

```
class AddCarEvent extends CarEvent
{

    protected $type = 'add';

}
```

---

```
class DeleteCarEvent extends CarEvent
{

    protected $type = 'delete';

    public function __construct(Car $car)
    {
        $this->car = (object) ['id' => $car->id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. For a temporary workaround I've created separate Event just for Delete, but Your solution looks better. Can I build base event class that my other event will extend? I have C# background and starting in Lumen. How should I build that class? I need a way to specify type and model, like generic class in C#. Ideally I would be able to pass another model to constructor. Could You please add this class to Your answer?

Comment: Sorry for such long delay on this. But I have one more related question. Can i clone object (Car in my case) so that my event will return not just id but full model. I know I must declare Event before I delete car and after that I must fire it, but this time Car won't be in my database and . I've tried creating clone just before I call delete, but without luck. I probably must add modified version of  `getRestoredPropertyValue`. How I should change it so that it will return item I've passed to event and will not try to get it from database? Can this be universal for other types events?

Comment: Basically I'd like to serialize model that is passed inside constructor of my event and avoid (if possible) querying database for new model (this is unneeded because I'm passing it inside constructor). I've read a bit about soft delete, but I'm not using it so any soft delete related serializers won't work.

Comment: @Misiu Ok, so you just want to get the Car data, with no need to "refresh" the model data from database or even check it exists. Then in the Event constructor `$this->car = $car->toArray();` so you serialize the data, not the Eloquent object itself.

Comment: @Thank You for reply, that's almost what I need. If I do delete then I'd like to avoid checking and refreshing, but in all other cases (add, update) I'd like to keep normal behavior, so I probably I must change `getRestoredPropertyValue` am I right?

Comment: @Misiu why not keeping separate event classes as updated answer, and do the `toArray` thing in DeleteCarEvent ?

Comment: I'd like to have single event class for each `Business Object`. If all it takes is overriding `getRestoredPropertyValue` then it would be awesome.